# non understandable error in a twirl file(scala+sbt+spray+twirl)

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I have a strange error when I try to compile a spray project whose twirl file is expected to display a list of RDV (meetings) between 2 dates:

```
> compile
[info] Compiling twirl template .../texte.scala.html to .../texte.template.scala
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources to /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/generated-twirl-sources/html/texte.template.scala:16: ')' expected but '=' found.
[error] Seq[Any](_display_(Seq[Any](/*2.2*/(rdvs:List[Rdv], de:String = "Entrez une date", jusque:String = "Entrez une date"))),format.raw/*2.84*/("""
[error]                                                               ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/generated-twirl-sources/html/texte.template.scala:120: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error] </html>"""))}
[error]             ^
[error] two errors found
[error] 2 problem(s) in Twirl template(s) found
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/twirl/texte.scala.html:2: ')' expected but '=' found.
[error] @(rdvs:List[Rdv], de:String = "Entrez une date", jusque:String = "Entrez une date") 
[error]                             ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/twirl/texte.scala.html:108: ')' expected but '}' found.
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 17 mars 2014 19:48:06
```

After some errors in the twirl compiled file, sbt gives me the corresponding error in the html file, but it's not understandable for me;

here is the twirl file:

```
@import metier.Objets.Rdv
@(rdvs:List[Rdv], de:String = "Entrez une date", jusque:String = "Entrez une date")

<!--   -->

<html>
<head>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<!-- jQuery 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>-->

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#aTable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[""]);
        $("#from").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#from").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
        $("#to").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            onClose : function(selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
</script>



</head>
@* This template is a simple html template --- (this text btw. is a
comment and is not rendered) *@

<form class="form-horizontal" id="signinForm" action="" method="post">

        <label>hello</label> <input name="nom" />
        <button data-bind="click: signin">CLICK ME!</button>
        <br /> <label for="from">De</label> <input type="text" id="from"
            name="from"> <label for="De">à</label> <input type="text"
            id="to" name="to">

</form>


<table id="aTable" class="display" width="500px" align="left">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Date examen</th>
            <th>Heure Examen</th>
            <th>Tél.</th>
            <th>Bureau</th>
            <th>Privé</th>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Libellé</th>
            <th>orderID</th>
            <th>Statut</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(rdv <- rdvs){
        <tr>
            <td>@rdv.nom</td>
            <td>@rdv.prénom</td>
            <td>@rdv.dateRDV</td>
            <td>@rdv.heureRDVString</td>
            <td>@rdv.telPortable</td>
            <td>@rdv.telBureau</td>
            <td>@rdv.telPrivé</td>
            <td>@rdv.siteRDV</td>
            <td>@rdv.typeRDV</td>
            <td>@rdv.libelléRDV</td>
            <td>@rdv.orderId</td>
            <td>@rdv.statut</td>

        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

only the beginning is concerned by the error.
can you help me?

ps: here is the part of the route treating the form of the previous twirl file:

```
post {
      formField( 'nom ,'from, 'to) { (name,de,jusque) =>
        println( "button clicked!" )
        respondWithMediaType( `text/html` ) {
          val listOfRdv:List[Rdv]=grab_rdv
          complete( html.texte(listOfRdv ).toString )
        }
      }
    }
```

thanks

PS : to answer to the comment, here is the new error when I remove the defaults values:

[

```
info] Compiling twirl template .../texte.scala.html to .../texte.template.scala
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources to /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/scala/com/example/MyService.scala:43: too many arguments for method apply: ()twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object texte
[error]           complete( html.texte( Nil ).toString )
[error]                               ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/scala/metier/Objets.scala:4: object io is not a member of package reflect
[error] import scala.reflect.io.File
[error]                      ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/scala/metier/Objets.scala:124: not found: value File
[error]         val fileToSave = File(fileString)
[error]                          ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/scala/metier/Objets.scala:127: not found: value File
[error]           val ancientFile = File(fileString + ".save")
[error]                             ^
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/generated-twirl-sources/html/texte.template.scala:16: not found: value rdvs
[error] Seq[Any](_display_(Seq[Any](/*2.2*/(rdvs:List[Rdv], de:String, jusque:String ))),format.raw/*2.45*/("""
[error]                                     ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] 1 problem(s) in Twirl template(s) found
[error] /Users/oliviersaint-eve/sms/SPRAY/spray-macaque/src/main/twirl/texte.scala.html:2: not found: value rdvs
[error] @(rdvs:List[Rdv], de:String, jusque:String )
[error]   ^
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 17 mars 2014 20:56:12
```

Again, it's incomprehensible, in my routes either I call the page with the parameter of type List[Rdv] or with Nil...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you cannot have default values in your template parameters. Try changing the second line like this:

```
@(rdvs: List[Rdv], de: String, jusque: String)
```

You can pass these values instead of keeping them as default ones.

Comment: hello, thanks. Please have a look at my question's edit!

Comment: ok, it works: I removed @import and changed Rdv to metier.Objets.Rdv; I changed a scala.reflect.File to java.lang.File(wrong import) and I added the 2 last String parameters the calls lacks in. thanks